# Volatility of a stochastic Process given by an SDE

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, itos-lemma, sde

I am currently working on this thesis: http://arks.princeton.edu/ark:/88435/dsp01vd66w212h and i am stuck on page 199. There we have a portfolio $P=\alpha F+\beta G $ with $\alpha +\beta =1$ and underlying process $dX_t=db_t+A(t,X_t)dt+B(t,X_t)dW_t$, where $b_t$ is a function of time and $W_t$ a standard Brownian motion.
With the It^{o} formula and the definition of $dX_t$ we get
\begin{align*}
    dP_t=\bigg[\alpha \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} (t,X_t)  +  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,X_t) A(t,X_t) +    \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 x^2} (t,X_t) B^2(t,X_t) \right) \  
        + \beta \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial t} (t,X_t)  +  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} (t,X_t) A(t,X_t) +    \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial^2 x^2} (t,X_t) B^2(t,X_t) \right) \bigg]dt \
        + \left[\alpha  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,X_t)  +    \beta  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} (t,X_t) \right]  dbt\
        +  \left[ \alpha  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t)  +  \beta  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t)   \right] dW_t
\end{align*}
Now the author states that the **volatility** is given by
\begin{align*}
\alpha  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t)  +  \beta  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t) 
\end{align*}
I understand that the volatility depends on this term but i dont unterstand that it is directly given by this term.
Furthermore i am confused how to calculate the variance in this case.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I am unable to access the paper but it might be a case of imprecise terminology. To me, this looks like the *instantaneous* volatility, whereas you might be thinking of the integrated volatility (which I believe can be computed via Ito isometry.)

Comment: The author is simply saying this is the coefficient of $dW$ in the above SDE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! The download link is at the bottom of the webpage. @nbbo2 what does this coefficient of the $dW$ term mean for volatility? In the next step, the author sets the "volatility" $\alpha  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t)  +  \beta  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} (t,X_t) B(t,X_t) =0$. So this term must have something to do with the volatility or?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to arks.princeton.edu probably because we are not authorized users.